# Al tratar de conectarme a una base de datos con codeigniter me dice que la variable $db no esta definida

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

estoy siguiendo un tutorial de codeigniter 4,para conectarme a una base de datos ya cree la base de datos llamada amsys, cree mi modelo llamado $registroUsoModel , configure el archivo.env, pero al tratar de hacer una consulta a esa base de datos creada desde un controlador con el siguiente código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <?php

namespace App\Controllers;


use App\Models\RegistroUsuModel;

class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
        {
           $registroUsoModel=new RegistroUsuModel($db);
            $registro=$registroUsoModel->findAll();
            var_dump($registro);
               return view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

me indica el siguiente error, la variable $db no esta definida, intente cambiando ($db) por ($this->db) pero no funciono.

Agradezco a quien me pueda guiar , donde tengo el error y donde debo modificar.

Comment: Es ideal quitar la imagen que contiene el código y colocar solo código y la explicación de tu duda

Comment: Pues eso, ¿dónde has definido a la variable `$db`?